# Dynamic images with Image class

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm trying to do a simple case, output an image which is saved in a `db.BlobProperty`. I've read all of the GAE docs but can't seem to figure this one out.

**Working:** renders in browser

```
photo = Photo.get(photo_key)
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
self.response.write( photo.image )
```

**Failing:** what I really want to do is modify the image using `images`

```
from google.appengine.api import images

photo = Photo.get(photo_key)
img = images.Image(photo.image)
# no actual processing/transforms, ruling out that as an issue
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
self.response.write( img )
```

I believe it's a header issue. For some reason, when I `write` a `Image` object GAE is encoding it. The working example just returns with the `image/png` the failing give `image/png; charset=utf-8`.

I'm not sure what else to do since I am explicitly setting the `Content-Type` header in both cases. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just use the `images.Image` object as the source for `self.response.write`. You need the actual data as a string, which you get from `img.execute_transforms()` even if you haven't asked for any transformations.

Comment: This works. To clarify for anyone else, `BadRequestError: Must specify at least one transformation` so I applied an `img.resize()` and it works just as expected. This makes since because why process an image that is not being altered. Thanks!

Comment: Or, use img.rotate (img, degress=360)